# Xpath get only first string of a node

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I am doing a web-scraping to a site and i just want to get the first string of a  node, i have tried already the child and contains function.

The html code that i have:

```
<div id="m0" style="visibility:visible; display:block;">
  <table class="fl">
   <tr bgcolor="white"><td class="v px3"></td>
     <td class="ch">
        <a title="Id: NetViet" class="A3">NetViet</a></td>
     <td class="cr" ">Clear</td>
   <tr bgcolor="white"><td class="v px3"></td>
     <td class="ch">
        <a title="Id: Vozrojdenie.tv" class="A3">VOTV</a></td>
   <tr bgcolor="white"><td class="v px3"></td>
     <td class="ch">
        <A class="A3" title="Id: Suryoyo Sat" HREF="http://www.suryoyosat.com/" TARGET="_blank">Suryoyo Sat</A></td>
     <td class="cr" ">Clear</td>

<div id="m1" style="visibility:visible; display:block;">
  <table class="fl">
   <tr bgcolor="#DDD0B8"><td class="v px3"></td>
     <td class="ch">
      <a title="Sporadic or full 16/9 transmission"></td>
     <td class="cr" ">Conax<br />Irdeto 2<br />Mediaguard 3<br />Nagravision 3<br />Viaccess 3.0</td>
   <tr bgcolor="#DDD0B8"><td class="v px3"></td>
     <td class="ch">
       <a title="Id: Sportklub HD" class="A3">Sport Klub HD Poland</a></td>
     <td class="cr" ">Conax<br />Mediaguard 3<br />Nagravision 3<br />Viaccess 3.0</td>
   <tr bgcolor="#DDD0B8"><td class="v px3"></td>
     <td class="ch">
       <a title="Id: Animal Planet HD" class="A3">Animal Planet HD</a></td>
     <td class="cr" ">Conax<br />Irdeto 2<br />Mediaguard 3<br />Nagravision 3<br />Viaccess 3.0</td>
```

I am using the xpath query:

```
encrypted=tree.xpath('//div[@id="%s"]/table[@class= "fl"]/tr/td[@class="cr"]/text()'%div)
```

it returns:

```
[['Clear','Clear','Clear'],['Conax','Irdeto 2','Mediaguard 3','Nagravision 3','Conax','Mediaguard 3','Nagravision 3', 'Viaccess 3.0',...]]
```

and i want it to return:

```
[['Clear','Clear','Clear'],['Conax','Conax','Conax',...]]
```

I am trying this query but it gives me nothing:

```
encrypted=tree.xpath('substring-before(//div[@id="%s"]/table[@class= "fl"]/tr/td[@class="cr"]/text(),"C")'%div)
```

Any idea? (I am using lxml and requests from python, xpath 1.0)

Comment: try `//div[@id="%s"]/table[@class= "fl"]/tr/td[@class="cr"]/text()[1]`

Comment: i already tried that, it gives me the first of each div and i want the first of each td

Comment: i think i got it with this:  `encrypted=tree.xpath('//div[@id="%s"]/table[@class= "fl"]/tr/td[@class="cr"]/child::text()[1]'%div)`